# How to find same characters in two random strings? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, string, loops

I am busy working through some problems I have found on the net and I feel like this should be simple but I am really struggling.

Say you have the string 'AbcDeFg' and the next string of 'HijKgLMnn', I want to be able to find the same characters in the string so in this case it would be 'g'.

Perhaps I wasn't giving enough information - I am doing Advent of Code and I am on [day 3](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/3). I just need help with the first bit which is where you are given a string of characters - you have to split the characters in half and then compare the 2 strings. You basically have to get the common character between the two. This is what I currently have:

```
file_data = File.read('Day_3_task1.txt')
arr = file_data.split("\n")

finals = []
arr.each do |x|
  len = x.length
  divided_by_two = len / 2
  second = x.slice!(divided_by_two..len).split('')
  first = x.split('')
  count = 0
  (0..len).each do |z|
    first.each do |y|
      if y == second[count]
        finals.push(y)
      end
    end
    count += 1
  end 
end

finals = finals.uniq
```

Hope that helps in terms of clarity :)

Comment: For each char `c` from the first string you should ensure it exists in the 2nd string. There are several ways to solve this task, with very different time/space characteristics: the most straightforward (and inefficient) algorithm literally follows the 1st sentence sentence (outer iteration over the 1st string to pick characters, inner iteration over the 2nd for each character) - you could start with it at least

Comment: If only these [chars](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/String.html#method-i-chars) were in an Array...then you could use [intersection](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-intersection).

Comment: _"I tried [...], but I keep running into errors"_ – show your attempt(s), please. It's easier to provide a helpful answer if we can see your code.

Comment: Your comment about "I tried deleting all unique characters..." is actually a bit interesting -- it's a real shame you haven't actually shared any of this code, so we can't comment on why it didn't work. I'm **suspicious** that this attempt would be flawed anyway, because: What if the one of the strings contains duplicate characters?

Comment: I edited the question to help with clarity :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to convert both strings to arrays with the `String#char` method and find the intersection of those arrays?
Like this:

```
string_one = 'AbcDeFg'.chars
string_two = 'HijKgLMnn'.chars
string_one & string_two # => ["g"]
```

Comment: `string_one` and `string_two` might not be the best variable names for arrays ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to use the method [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scan) with the regular expression

```
rgx = /(.)(?!.*\1.*_)(?=.*_.*\1)/
```

I'm not advocating this approach. I merely thought some readers might find it interesting.

Suppose

```
str1 = 'AbcDgeFg'
str2 = 'HijKgLMnbn'
```

Now form the string

```
str = "#{str1}_#{str2}"
  #=> "AbcDeFg_HijKgLMnbn"
```

I've assumed the strings contain letters only, in which case they are separated in `str` with any character other than a letter. I've used an underscore. Naturally, if the strings could contain underscores a different separator would have to be used.

We then compute

```
str.scan(rgx).flatten
  #=> ["b", "g"]
```

---

[Array#flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) is needed because

```
str.scan(rgx)
  #=>[["b"], ["g"]]
```

---

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting:

```
rgx =
  /
  (.)    # match any character, same to capture group 1
  (?!    # begin a negative lookahead
    .*   # match zero or more characters 
    \1   # match the contents of capture group 1
    .*   # match zero or more characters 
    _    # match an underscore
  )      # end the negative lookahead
  (?=    # begin a positive lookahead
    .*   # match zero or more characters 
    _    # match an underscore
    .*   # match zero or more characters 
    \1   # match the contents of capture group 1
  )      # end the positive lookahead
  /x     # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Note that if a character appears more than once in `str1` and at least once in `str2` the negative lookahead ensures that only the last one in `str1` is matched, to avoid returning duplicates.

---

Alternatively, one could write

```
str.gsub(rgx).to_a
```

The uses the (fourth) form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) which takes a single argument and no block and returns an enumerator.